# how can i dynamically change id values from created elements to match the index of the items within an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm working on a todo list and for each element that's created a project is being added to that new element. I created an id value that increases every time someone adds a project to the array but i do not know how to change their values to match the items index within the array whenever a user deletes an item. Therefore, once the array has mutated using splice the id values do not match the index of the item being rendered.

you can click on the item to see the id value that correlates to that element.

```js
//class for a single project
class Project {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasksArr = [];
    }
    get nameOfProject() {
        return this.name;
    }
    addTasksToProject(name, dueDate) {
        let newTask = new Task(name, dueDate);
        this.tasksArr.push(newTask);
    }
}
//class for a group of projects 
class Projects {
    constructor() {
        this.listOfProjects = [new Project("Sample Project")];
    }
    addProjectToList(name) {
        let p = new Project(name);
        this.listOfProjects.push(p);
        return p
    }
    get allProjects() {
       return this.listOfProjects;
    }
    get numOfProjects() {
        return this.listOfProjects.length;
    }
}

let projects = new Projects();
let projArr = projects.allProjects;
let projectId = 0;
let selectedProj = null;

function selectProject(e) {
    let currentProj = projArr[e.currentTarget.id];
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(currentProj.name);
}

projArr.forEach(renderProjects);
function renderProjects(project) {
    const newProjectDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const dltBtn = document.createElement("button");
  const projectDom = document.getElementById("project-list");
    newProjectDiv.textContent = project.nameOfProject;
    dltBtn.textContent = "delete";
    newProjectDiv.classList.add("project-item");
    newProjectDiv.appendChild(dltBtn);
    projectDom.append(newProjectDiv);
    newProjectDiv.id = projectId;
    dltBtn.addEventListener("click", (index) => {
        if(projArr[index] === dltBtn[index]) {
            projArr.splice(projArr.indexOf(project), 1);
            newProjectDiv.remove();
        }
    });
    newProjectDiv.addEventListener("click", selectProject);
    projectId++;
    console.log(project.nameOfProject); 
}
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addProjectBtn);

function addProjectBtn() {
    let projName = prompt("name");
    let pushProj = projects.addProjectToList(projName);
    renderProjects(pushProj);
    console.log(projects.allProjects);
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>

<div id="project-list" class="project-list"></div>
```

Comment: If the id were to always match the index, then there would be no need for an id.  The point of an id is that it remains constant for a specific item no matter what else gets added, removed, or reordered.

Comment: @Malcolm is see, what should i use in this specific scenario to consistently match the index if not the id attribute?

Comment: In general, use the id as the identifier of the item when you print it out the item's information, and just use the index to loop through the list.  If you need to look up items by their id and you keep your list sorted you could implement a bisection search, or you could switch to using a Map rather than an array.